# swift: how to replace if else on switch case statements

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I have this `if else` check:

```
var aItem: CGFloat = 0

if item == 0 {
    aItem = 457

} else if item == 1 {
    aItem = 576

} else if item == 2 {
    aItem = 758

}

print(aItem)
```

I want to replace this piece of code with a `switch` case statements. How to do it?

I tried:

```
    var aItem: CGFloat = 0

    switch item {
    case _ where item == 0:

        aItem = 457

    case _ where item == 1:

        aItem = 576

    case _ where item == 2:

        aItem = 758

    default:
        print("this is impossible")
    }
```

It is works but is is the best solution? Maybe can somehow simplify this code?

And what is better to use? if else or switch case statements?

Comment: Show what you tried. Explain what problems you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy updated.

Comment: You should read about `switch` in the Swift book under [Conditional Statements](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be written as:

```
let aItem: CGFloat

switch item {
case 0:
    aItem = 457
case 1:
    aItem = 576
case 2:
    aItem = 758
default:
    aItem = 0
    print("this is impossible")
}

print(aItem)
```

If it's a fact that your `item` can only be 0, 1, or 2, I would do:

```
let anItem: CGFloat = [457, 576, 758][item]
```

In this case there's little difference between using `if else` or `switch`. Pick your favorite. `if` and `switch` have there strengths. Use which ever best fits the code/logic you need. Or, as in this case, don't use either.

Comment: `aItem` can be a `let` constant. The compiler ensures definitive (and single) initialization, without needing to be `var`.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, declare as `let aItem: CGFloat` and then be sure it gets a value in every `case` and `default`. But that wasn't the focus of the question (or the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another interesting alternative (which can be useful, for example, when initializing an instance property:

```
struct SomeType {
    let someProperty: Int = {
        let x = 0

        switch x { // Unfortunately, `x` can't be an instance member of self.
        case 0: return 457
        case 1: return 576
        case 2: return 758
        default:
            fatalError("this is impossible")
        }
    }()
}
```